# Xamarin FlexLayout not binding correctly

Tags: c#, xamarin, viewmodel

I have added multiple FlexLayouts inside a StackLayout. All FlexLayouts have a BindableLayout that contain checkboxes. Some of the flexlayouts have an IsVisible binding depending on other data. Now the problem is that the bindings of the FlexLayouts are incredibly unreliable and every time I go to a different view and back to this one, there are different ways the data is displayed. eg. some FlexLayouts will show the correct checkboxes checked, some will show them all unchecked, even though they are supposed to be checked, according to the database. The data is not consistent, which means different flexboxes will check or uncheck every time I go in this view.

I have to add that I tried at first with CollectionViews instead of the FlexLayout and with that all checkboxes would always show correctly, but if an Entry would change its visibility, that would not show, which I assumed it's because they would not change position to make space for the new entries.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the part of the ViewModel:

```
 public async Task InitData(int wellID)
        {
            try
            {
                IsBusy = true;

                ArtificialLiftList = new ObservableCollection<CountModel>
            {
                new CountModel() { ID = 2, Description = "ESP", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 3, Description = "PCP Progressive Cavity Pump", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 4, Description = "Jet Pump", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 6, Description = "Rod Pump", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 7, Description = "Continuous Gas Lift", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 8, Description = "Natural flowing", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 9, Description = "Plunger Lift", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 10, Description = "Intermittent Gas Lift", IsChecked = false }
            };

                ProductionTypeList = new ObservableCollection<CountModel>
            {
                new CountModel() { ID = 1, Description = "Oil", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 2, Description = "Gas", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 3, Description = "Gas Condensate", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 4, Description = "Water", IsChecked = false }
            };

                OnshoreOffshoreList = new ObservableCollection<BaseModel>
            {
                new BaseModel() { ID = 1, Description = "Onshore" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 2, Description = "Offshore" }
            };

                WellStatusList = new ObservableCollection<BaseModel>
            {
                new BaseModel() { ID = 0, Description = "Unknown" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 1, Description = "Pending Installation" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 2, Description = "In Service" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 6, Description = "On Hold" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 8, Description = "Decommissioned" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 9, Description = "Live Enquiry" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 10, Description = "Survey Pending" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 11, Description = "On Trial" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 13, Description = "Rejected Enquiry" }
            };

                ESPManufacturerList = new ObservableCollection<BaseModel>
            {
                new BaseModel() { ID = 1, Description = "GE" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 2, Description = "Schlumberger Reda" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 3, Description = "Baker Centrilift" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 4, Description = "Summit Halliburton" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 5, Description = "Borets" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 6, Description = "Novomet" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 7, Description = "Other" }
            };

                ReservoirDriveFluidList = new ObservableCollection<CountModel>
            {
                new CountModel() { ID = 1, Description = "Seawater", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 2, Description = "Produced Water", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 3, Description = "Hydrocarbon Gas", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 4, Description = "Steam", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 5, Description = "Carbon Dioxide", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 6, Description = "Chemical EOR", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 7, Description = "None", IsChecked = false }
            };

                WellSystemTypeList = new ObservableCollection<BaseModel>
            {
                new BaseModel() { ID = 1, Description = "Process Plant" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 2, Description = "Injection Well" },
                new BaseModel() { ID = 3, Description = "Production Well" }
            };

                ChemicalList = new ObservableCollection<CountModel>
            {
                new CountModel() { ID = 1, Description = "Alkaline Surfactant", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 2, Description = "Surfactant", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel() { ID = 3, Description = "Polymer", IsChecked = false }
            };

                ScaleTypeList = new ObservableCollection<CountModel>
            {
                new CountModel { ID = 1, Description = "Other", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel { ID = 2, Description = "Barium Sulphate", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel { ID = 3, Description = "Calcium Carbonate", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel { ID = 4, Description = "Calcium Sulphate", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel { ID = 5, Description = "Strontium Sulphate", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel { ID = 7, Description = "Halite", IsChecked = false },
                new CountModel { ID = 8, Description = "Bacteria", IsChecked = false }
            };

                SQLiteAsyncConnection db;

                var databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "MyData.db");

                db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);

                var well = await db.Table<Well>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.ID == wellID);

                if (well != null)
                {
                    ID = well.ID;
                    Description = well.Description;
                    FieldName = well.FieldName;
                    CompanyName = well.CompanyName;
                    WellGroupID = well.WellGroupID;
                    Latitude = well.Latitude;
                    Longitude = well.Longitude;
                    ESPManufacturer = well.ESPManufacturerID == null ? null : ESPManufacturerList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == well.ESPManufacturerID);
                    Notes = well.Notes;
                    OtherManufacturer = well.OtherManufacturer;
                    OtherScaleType = well.OtherScaleType;
                    ProposedInstallDate = well.ProposedInstallDate;
                    ActualInstallDate = well.ActualInstallDate;
                    OnshoreOffshore = OnshoreOffshoreList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == well.OnshoreOffshore);
                    Status = WellStatusList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == well.Status);
                    UnitID = well.UnitID == null ? 0 : well.UnitID;

                    _ = await db.CreateTableAsync<WellFluidType>();
                    var fluidType = await db.Table<WellFluidType>().Where(t => t.WellID == wellID).ToListAsync();
                    foreach (var item in fluidType)
                    {
                        foreach (var item2 in ProductionTypeList)
                        {
                            if (item.FluidTypeID == item2.ID)
                            {
                                item2.IsChecked = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    _ = await db.CreateTableAsync<WellApplication>();
                    var applications = await db.Table<WellApplication>().Where(t => t.WellID == wellID).ToListAsync();
                    foreach (var item in applications)
                    {
                        foreach (var item2 in ArtificialLiftList)
                        {
                            if (item.ApplicationID == item2.ID)
                            {
                                item2.IsChecked = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    _ = await db.CreateTableAsync<WellReservoirFluid>();
                    var wellReservoirFluids = await db.Table<WellReservoirFluid>().Where(t => t.WellID == wellID).ToListAsync();
                    foreach (var item in wellReservoirFluids)
                    {
                        foreach (var item2 in ReservoirDriveFluidList)
                        {
                            if (item.ReservoirFluidID == item2.ID)
                            {
                                item2.IsChecked = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    _ = await db.CreateTableAsync<WellScaleType>();
                    var wellScaleTypes = await db.Table<WellScaleType>().Where(t => t.WellID == wellID).ToListAsync();
                    foreach (var item in wellScaleTypes)
                    {
                        foreach (var item2 in ScaleTypeList)
                        {
                            if (item.ScaleTypeID == item2.ID)
                            {
                                item2.IsChecked = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    _ = await db.CreateTableAsync<WellChemicalEOR>();
                    var wellChemicalEORs = await db.Table<WellChemicalEOR>().Where(t => t.WellID == wellID).ToListAsync();
                    foreach (var item in wellChemicalEORs)
                    {
                        foreach (var item2 in ChemicalList)
                        {
                            if (item.ChemicalID == item2.ID)
                            {
                                item2.IsChecked = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    WellSystemTypeID = well.WellSystemTypeID == null ? null : WellSystemTypeList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == well.WellSystemTypeID);
                    ProcessPlantType = well.ProcessPlantType;
                    ChemicalEORVisible = WellSystemTypeID == null ? false : WellSystemTypeID.ID == 3 && ReservoirDriveFluidList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == 6 && t.IsChecked == true) != null;
                    OtherScaleVisible = ScaleTypeList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == 1 && t.IsChecked == true) != null;
                    LiftingMethodsVisible = WellSystemTypeID == null ? false : WellSystemTypeID.ID == 3;
                    ReservoirFluidsVisible = WellSystemTypeID == null ? false : WellSystemTypeID.ID == 3;
                    ProcessPlantVisible = WellSystemTypeID == null ? false : WellSystemTypeID.ID == 1;
                    OtherESPManufacturerVisible = ESPManufacturer == null ? false : (ESPManufacturer.ID == 7);
                    ESPSelectedVisible = WellSystemTypeID == null ? false : WellSystemTypeID.ID == 3 && ArtificialLiftList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == 2 && t.IsChecked) != null;
                }
                IsBusy = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                \\Do something
            }
        }
```

View .xaml :

```
<FlexLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Fluid Types:" />
                    <FlexLayout Direction="Column"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                        x:Name="ProductionTypeCollection"
                        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ProductionTypeList}">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout Padding="10" Grid.Row="1" Spacing="50" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:DataType="model:CountModel">
                                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Name" Color="Blue" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                       FontSize="Large"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </FlexLayout>

                    <Label Text="Reservoir Drive Fluid:" IsVisible="{Binding ReservoirFluidsVisible}" x:Name="ReservoirFluidsLabel"/>
                    <FlexLayout Direction="Column"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                        x:Name="ReservoirDriveFluidCollection"
                        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ReservoirDriveFluidList}"                       
                        IsVisible="{Binding ReservoirFluidsVisible}" >
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout Padding="10" Grid.Row="1" Spacing="50" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:DataType="model:CountModel">
                                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Name" Color="Blue" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" CheckedChanged="ReservoirDriveFluid_Changed" />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                       FontSize="Large"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </FlexLayout>

                    <Label Text="Chemical EOR Type:" IsVisible="{Binding ChemicalEORVisible}" x:Name="ChemicalEORLabel"/>
                    <FlexLayout Direction="Column"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                        x:Name="ChemicalCollection"
                        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ChemicalList}"
                        IsVisible="{Binding ChemicalEORVisible}" >
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout Padding="10" Grid.Row="1" Spacing="50" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:DataType="model:CountModel">
                                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Name" Color="Blue" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                       FontSize="Large"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </FlexLayout>

                    <Label Text="Lifting Methods:" IsVisible="{Binding LiftingMethodsVisible}" x:Name="LiftingMethodsLabel"/>
                    <FlexLayout Direction="Column"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                        x:Name="LiftingMethodsCollection"
                        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ArtificialLiftList}"
                        IsVisible="{Binding LiftingMethodsVisible}">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout Padding="10" Grid.Row="1" Spacing="50" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:DataType="model:CountModel">
                                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Name" Color="Blue" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" CheckedChanged="SelectedArtificialLiftTypeIndexChanged" />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                       FontSize="Large"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </FlexLayout>
                    
                    <Label Text=" ESP Manufacturer:" IsVisible="{Binding ESPSelectedVisible}" x:Name="ESPManufacturersLabel" />
                    <Picker x:Name="ESPManufacturerPicker"
                            IsVisible="{Binding ESPSelectedVisible}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ESPManufacturerList}"
                            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Description}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding ESPManufacturer}"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            SelectedIndexChanged="SelectedESPManufacturerIndexChanged">
                    </Picker>

                    <Label Text="Other Manufacturer:" IsVisible="{Binding OtherESPManufacturerVisible}" x:Name="OtherManufacturerLabel"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding OtherManufacturer}"  IsVisible="{Binding OtherESPManufacturerVisible}" x:Name="OtherManufacturer" FontSize="Medium"/>

                    <Label Text="Treatment:" />
                    <FlexLayout Direction="Column" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                        x:Name="ScaleTypeCollection"
                        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ScaleTypeList}">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout Padding="10" Grid.Row="1" Spacing="50" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:DataType="model:CountModel">
                                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Name" Color="Blue" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" CheckedChanged="Scale_Changed" />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                       FontSize="Large"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </FlexLayout>

                    <Label Text="Other Treatment:" IsVisible="{Binding OtherScaleVisible}" x:Name="OtherScaleLabel"/>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding OtherScaleType}" IsVisible="{Binding OtherScaleVisible}" x:Name="OtherScaleType" FontSize="Medium"/>

                    <Label Text="Notes:" FontSize="Medium"/>
                    <Editor Text="{Binding Notes}" x:Name="Notes" AutoSize="TextChanges"  FontSize="Medium"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </FlexLayout>
```

View .xaml.cs:

```
 WellViewModel viewModel;
        int WellID { get; set; }
        public WellInfo(int wellID)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            WellID = wellID;
            viewModel = new WellViewModel(wellID);
            BindingContext = viewModel;
        }
        //protected override async void OnAppearing()
        //{
        //    base.OnAppearing();
        //    await viewModel.InitData(WellID);
        //}
        public async void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var wellDataStore = new WellDataStore();
            await wellDataStore.AddWell(int.Parse(ID.Text), Description.Text, FieldName.Text, viewModel.CompanyName, viewModel.WellGroupID, LatitudeCoordinates.Text, LongitudeCoordinates.Text, (BaseModel)ESPManufacturerPicker.SelectedItem, Notes.Text, OtherManufacturer.Text, ProposedInstallDate.NullableDate, ActualInstallDate.NullableDate, (BaseModel)OnshoreOffshore.SelectedItem, (BaseModel)WellStatus.SelectedItem, viewModel.UnitID, (BaseModel)WellSystemTypeID.SelectedItem, ProcessPlantType.Text, viewModel.ReservoirDriveFluidList, viewModel.ChemicalList, viewModel.ScaleTypeList, viewModel.ArtificialLiftList, viewModel.ProductionTypeList, OtherScaleType.Text) ;
            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Saved");
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
        private void Scale_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in viewModel.ScaleTypeList)
            {
                if (item.ID == 1 && item.IsChecked)
                {
                    OtherScaleType.IsVisible = true;
                    OtherScaleLabel.IsVisible = true;
                }
                else if (item.ID == 1 && !item.IsChecked)
                {
                    OtherScaleType.IsVisible = false;
                    OtherScaleLabel.IsVisible = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void SelectedArtificialLiftTypeIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //you can also use SelectedItem

            foreach (var item in viewModel.ArtificialLiftList)
            {
                if (item.IsChecked && item.ID == 2)
                {
                    ESPManufacturerPicker.IsVisible = true;
                    ESPManufacturersLabel.IsVisible = true;
                }
                else if(!item.IsChecked && item.ID == 2)
                {
                    ESPManufacturerPicker.IsVisible = false;
                    ESPManufacturersLabel.IsVisible = false;
                }
            }
        }
        private void SelectedESPManufacturerIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //you can also use SelectedItem

            if (ESPManufacturerPicker.SelectedIndex == 6)
            {
                OtherManufacturer.IsVisible = true;
                OtherManufacturerLabel.IsVisible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                OtherManufacturer.IsVisible = false;
                OtherManufacturerLabel.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }
        private void SelectedWellSystemIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //you can also use SelectedItem

            if (WellSystemTypeID.SelectedItem == viewModel.WellSystemTypeList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == 1))
            {
                ProcessPlantLabel.IsVisible = true;
                ProcessPlantType.IsVisible = true;
                ReservoirFluidsLabel.IsVisible = false;
                ReservoirDriveFluidCollection.IsVisible = false;
                LiftingMethodsLabel.IsVisible = false;
                LiftingMethodsCollection.IsVisible = false;
                ChemicalEORLabel.IsVisible = false;
                ChemicalCollection.IsVisible = false;
                ESPManufacturerPicker.IsVisible = false;
                ESPManufacturersLabel.IsVisible = false;
            }
            else if (WellSystemTypeID.SelectedItem == viewModel.WellSystemTypeList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == 2))
            {
                ProcessPlantLabel.IsVisible = false;
                ProcessPlantType.IsVisible = false;
                ReservoirFluidsLabel.IsVisible = false;
                ReservoirDriveFluidCollection.IsVisible = false;
                LiftingMethodsLabel.IsVisible = false;
                LiftingMethodsCollection.IsVisible = false;
                ChemicalEORLabel.IsVisible = false;
                ChemicalCollection.IsVisible = false;
                ESPManufacturerPicker.IsVisible = false;
                ESPManufacturersLabel.IsVisible = false;
            }
            else if (WellSystemTypeID.SelectedItem == viewModel.WellSystemTypeList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == 3))
            {
                ProcessPlantLabel.IsVisible = false;
                ProcessPlantType.IsVisible = false;
                ReservoirFluidsLabel.IsVisible = true;
                ReservoirDriveFluidCollection.IsVisible = true;
                LiftingMethodsLabel.IsVisible = true;
                LiftingMethodsCollection.IsVisible = true;
                ChemicalEORLabel.IsVisible = false;
                ChemicalCollection.IsVisible = false;
                ESPManufacturerPicker.IsVisible = false;
                ESPManufacturersLabel.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }
        private void ReservoirDriveFluid_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in viewModel.ReservoirDriveFluidList)
            {

                if (item.ID == 6 && item.IsChecked)
                {
                    ChemicalEORLabel.IsVisible = true;
                    ChemicalCollection.IsVisible = true;
                }
                else if (item.ID == 6 && !item.IsChecked)
                {
                    ChemicalEORLabel.IsVisible = false;
                    ChemicalCollection.IsVisible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add to question the declaration of `item`. Especially its `IsChecked` property. Sounds like that property is missing `OnPropertyChanged();` in its setter. MAYBE could also be due to setting `item.IsChecked = ...;` in code that is not running on the UI thread (MainThread).

Comment: `IsChecked` is part of the `CountModel` model which most of my observable collections in this instance have implemented as a class. eg. `private ObservableCollection<CountModel> _productionTypeList;
  public ObservableCollection<CountModel> ProductionTypeList { get { return _productionTypeList; } set { _productionTypeList = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProductionTypeList)); }  }` . The declaration of `item` is present in the .xaml.cs. It is part of the `foreach` statements.

Comment: Does every FlexLayout has incorrect checkbox？

Comment: No, but they will also change every time I go back to the view. So if first FlexLayout is correct on first try, next try is incorrect, third time might be correct again.

Comment: Please **add to question** the declaration of `CountModel`, including declaration of `IsChecked` property. Need to determine if there is some issue that might cause XAML to not see the change to IsChecked. [I also recommend copying the code you put in comment above, into the question. It is much easier to read as part of question.]